# executing a file in C which uses the math library

Tags: c, gcc

I was trying to execute a file which uses the math library(more specifically it was using the sqrt() function). So I typed gcc fileName.c -o fileName, it kept saying "undefined reference to `sqrt'". But then when I was googling, someone said to add -lm at the end of my gcc call, but I don't understand why, can someone explain? Thanks.

Sam

Comment: `gcc` doesn't include by default the mathematical functions while linking. `-l` is a  linker option, `m` is the library name.

Comment: @MarounMaroun:  Post answers as answers rather than comments.  That is definitely an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C compilation has two distinct steps: compilation to object code, and linking. In compilation to object code, files are compiled as they are, and any external symbols (like those you get by including a header) are left as "blanks." The next stage, linking, is where those blanks are filled in. For many libraries, you have to tell gcc where to look, so you must give a `-l` flag (in this case, `-lm` for math).

Answer (score 2):

Adding `-lm` tells gcc to link against the math libarary.

```
-l<name> link against the library with name <name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly you need `-lm` in the invocation of the linker (ld) rather than the compiler, but gcc can invoke the linker after compilation and will forward the argument.  In more complex projects, you would invoke the linker separately.

The command line options for the linker are described [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.html#Options), while those for the compiler are described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/index.html#toc_Invoking-GCC).

The option `-l`*namespec* links the static library named lib*namespec*.a, whereas `-l:`*filename*, links the library *filename*.  An alternative form `--library=`*namespec* or `--library=`*filename* is supported.

`-lm` links libm.a - the math library.  The non math part of the standard library is in libc.a, but this is normally linked by default so i snot specified explicitly.